# Import-Module : The specified module 'SqlServer' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: sql-server, powershell, module

Well, hello there!

I'm working on a Script to get the Sql Job History and need to use the "SqlServer" Module. It's installed but I can't import it due to the Error Message above. When I got to the Modules Path, the Folder "SqlServer" exists and isn't empty. Don't get the problem here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you compared the file it is actually looking for with the files in the folder?  Also, check the exact path, make sure there isn't an extra \ in there somewhere, or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, already checked the $env:PSModulePath Variable. Didn't find anything there. Also added the Path a second time to make sure it'll go through this Folder. Doesn't work still.
How do I check the file it is looking for? I mean it doesn't say the name of the file on the Error message so how do I know which file powershell is looking for?

Comment: Which version of powershell/sql/operating system?

Comment: PSVersion 5.0.10586.117; Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 12.0.5571.0; SQL Server 2014; Operating System Server 2012

Answer (score 14):

I just ran into this on SQL Server 2017 (on Windows Server 2016) and found your question in the process. I then went and fired up our older SQL Server 2014 (Windows Server 2012) machine and found the same issue. Here's a couple options everyone can try to save some time (as I realize the question is kind of old and I'm assuming the OP found a solution already):

**1)** At a powershell command run: `Install-Module -Name SqlServer`
You might need the -AllowClobber parameter like this:

`Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber`

The thing here is that module is installed to the following path on both 2012 and 2016 servers:

`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer (rather than Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules)`

**2)** Another option is to try the `SQLPS` module by changing in your script:

`Import-Module -Name SqlServer`

To:

`Import-Module -Name SQLPS`

You will find `SQLPS` in the Microsoft SQL Server directory structure here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules
```

My script works with both SQL modules now, but the output actually looks better with SQLPS at this point...

[You can find more on all of the above at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

With TLS v1.0 and v1.1 being deprecated on Microsoft Services services in 2022/Q2, this error comes up again on non-updated Windows and/or PS versions.

The issue is solved by forcing PS to use TLS v1.2 and an updated NuGet version ...

```
   [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
   
   Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -RequiredVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```

... **before** running `Import-Module -Name SqlServer`.

As pointed out at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264972/how-can-i-install-the-sql-server-powershell-module-on-an-offline-machine) related question in [DBA/StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: there is also a different approach to use `Save-Module sqlserver -path c:\tmp`